Yup - how to tell which fields are optional
I'm building a validation UI that uses yup to check whether each schema is valid or not. I do this by running a single object against multiple small 'chunks' of the schema, representing each form step.
Part of the requirements are that I don't want to immediately flag up schemas as completed/valid if they are completely optional. For example
const step3 = object({ foo: string().optional() })
step3.isValidSync({}) // true

Now I am currently doing something like:
const allOptional = Object.entries(step3.fields).every(([key, schema]) => schema.spec.optional)
This is a bit of a naive approach as it assumes the object is flat, but for this example it works. The result is I get a flag of whether or not every field in the schema is optional, and as such, behave differently. Where this fails is, if its conditionally optional.
Given:

const step3 = object({ foo: string().optional().when('bar', { is: true, then: string().required()})
step3.isValidSync({}) // true
step3.isValidSync({ bar: true }) // false

But running this against my optional code, it would still flag up that all fields are optional, even when the bar is set to true.
In short, i'd like to get the field.spec object, but to consider that spec based on the values of the form at that time.
Is this possible? For now, my workaround (and maybe even the better solution) is to not run validation for steps unless they have been 'visited', but I would like to try and get this logic working for other purposes.

Don't use YUP, but looking at the docs, wound't it be -> then: (skema) => skema.required()
